# Animate Link underline on click as opposed to on hover?

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, underline

Having trouble getting my head around how I can recreate this effect as an on click as opposed to on hover?

I'm not great with jQuery so having trouble working out how I can trigger this to happen on click. I came across this website to help create the effect I'm going for (Underline Left to Right). The demo can be seen in the following link...

http://bradsknutson.com/blog/css-sliding-underline/

I'm currently using the following js to fade in a div and I want the line to slide in at them same time.

New jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/tfgou78c/4/

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('.submit_button').click(function() {
        var elem = $('.form_wrap');
        if (elem.css('display') == 'none') {
            elem.fadeIn(1750);
        }
        else {
            elem.fadeOut(1750);
        }
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.form_wrap {
 display: none;
 }

/* sliding underline LEFT TO RIGHT */
.sliding-u-l-r {
display: inline-block;
}

.sliding-u-l-r:after {
content: '';
display: block;
height: 3px;
width: 0;
background: transparent;
transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
}

.sliding-u-l-r:hover:after {
width: 100%;
background: blue;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried changing the `:hover` to `:active`?

Comment: I've just edited my question would the same still apply with regards to js? I haven't tried this yet.

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tfgou78c/2/ ?

Comment: Thanks for the demo, this is what I want except how would i integrate that with my current js?

Comment: Both the answers that have been given are using JavaScript to switch out the class. I would do it in CSS as I recommended in my first comment.

Comment: I can't get :active to work, would I replace :hover to :active or should I apply :active to the button triggering the animation?

Comment: `.sliding-u-l-r:hover:after` would become `.sliding-u-l-r:active:after` - The animation would show while you're holding your mouse button down, and disappear after. The JavaScript solutions listed would keep it after you've released the mouse button.

Comment: I see ok I think the jquery is what i need but thank you anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this method are using the CSS event `:hover` you can't change that for `click` just on the code because there is no method for `click` on CSS. You can have:

1. You tag this with Jquery so you can change the CSS match to:

   ```
   .sliding-u-l-r:hover:after
   ```

   to

   ```
   .sliding-u-l-r.clicked:after
   ```

   And then with Jquery:

   ```
   $('.sliding-u-l-r').on('click',function(){
      $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
   })
   ```

   Check this [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gvpr9w06/)

Comment: You did what I was trying to do, but couldn't. I tried using addClass but that updated the DOM too fast. Forgot about toggleClass. +1

Comment: Thanks for the response this was what I wanted to achieve but to somehow integrate it with my existing js?

Comment: @user2498890 You can't just add the toggleClass function into your current click handler?

Comment: @user2498890 as @CalvinScherle suggest just add the line `$(this)...` to your actual handler

Comment: So I can just add that line to my current js? Really sorry not great with this.

Comment: @user2498890 yep just add the same as the fiddle in your js and don't forget to make the change i mention on the CSs

Comment: @Danko this doesn't work.. or maybe your fiddle has a problem, but anyhow nothing happens when I click on the link

Comment: I've almost got it can anyone see where i'm going wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/tfgou78c/4/ It's doing what I want on fadeout but not on fade in.

Comment: @user2498890 seems like a bug when you set the display:none to that parent the after element is removed :/

Comment: Oh i see, do you think there might be a way to do it with opacity instead of display?

Comment: Ah perfect! I think if I play around with timings its exactly what I need. Thanks so much for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like http://jsfiddle.net/y4wuurt9/ ?

```js
$('.underline-thing').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('lined');
});
```

```css
.underline-thing {
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.underline-thing:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 3px;
    background: blue;
    -webkit-transition: width 250ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: width 250ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: width 250ms ease-in-out;
    transition: width 250ms ease-in-out;
}

.underline-thing.lined:after {
    width: 100%;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="underline-thing" href="#">Test Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

On click you wouldn't want it to stay would you?
Here's a pure css version that gets underlined on click:

```css
a:active{
  text-decoration:underline;
}
a{
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">click me and hold!</a>
```