# Display:none Removing Pseudo-elements

Tags: css, pseudo-element

Hi I was answer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26466949/2887133) and I notice an strange behavior

### The Context

I have an HTML structure like this:

```
<div class="btn">
    Click me
</div>
<div class="element">
    Div Box With Pseudo Element
</div>
```

And CSS <sup>Just the relevant</sup>

```
.element {
    display:none;
}
.element:after {
    content:" ";
    display:block;
    width:0;
    background:black;
    transition:6s ease;
}
.element.clicked:after {
    width:100%;
}
```

Where the `element` needs to be `display:none` and need to be show/hide when click the `btn` element. That works fine with Jquery and `fadeToggle`.

Also I add a `class` to animate a pseudo-element with `transition` and `width`. Need to animate at the same time of the `fade` on the parent.

### The problem

If you see this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/857dxph1/1/), you can notice at first click the expected behavior is the pseudo-element grows form `0` to `100%` but instead is `100%` without grow.

If you click again then it's fine changing from `100%` to `0`

### Question

I notice whit the inspector that setting `display:none` to the element makes the pseudo-element disappear.

[image]

This causes the element can't be from `0` to `100%` since doesn't exist.

**Anyone Knows How to stop that behavior or how to avoid the non-render of the element. I was wonder about the form pseudo-elements were rendered and If they need a Visible parent**

*This issue doesn't happen with `visibiliy` or `opacity` just with `display`*

Comment: display of 'none' does not create an invisible box; it creates no box at all. so by all accounts (from browser perspective ) there is no div

Comment: fadeToggle sets the element to display: none; once he's done. Why not make the animation with css? http://jsfiddle.net/857dxph1/3/

Comment: @Pogrindis good point I think that since the element is still in the DOM there's no reason to the pseudo-element disappear.

Comment: @JonasGrumann because the element needs to be display:none

Comment: I used jquery v 1.11.0 instead of the 2.x and had no problem. Maybe check your version. (This was in IE11)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this *issue* lies in the fact of how CSS `transition` works. As you well know a css transiton is applied when an element has a property changed **from one value to another**.

But in your scenario, the property isn't in fact changing. A pseudo element does not exists while its parent is in the `display: none` property. So when you call the `fadeToggle()`, the element becomes `display: block` and *then pseudo is created.*

But immediately it is already affected by the `.clicked` class of the parent, which gives the pseudo a `width: 100%` property.

So, essencially, the `width` property is never changed. It goes from "*non existent*" to "*100%*", therefore, no transition is applied.

**EDIT**

So, what you really need is to revert the order of the apply of `.clicked` class to *after* the fade started:

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/857dxph1/11/)

```
$('.element').stop().fadeToggle(3000).toggleClass('clicked');
```